# Converting from long to BitSet - what is the meaning of these bitwise operations?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am trying to convert the following code from `long` to `BitSet` (because I want to make boards longer than 64 cells):

https://blackflux.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/peg-solitaire-brute-force/

And I'm currently trying to convert the following part:

```
// create the two possible moves for the three added pegs
// (this function assumes that the pegs are in one continuous line)
private static void createMoves(int bit1, int bit2, int bit3, ArrayList<long[]> moves) {
    moves.add(new long[]{(1L << bit1), (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3),
            (1L << bit1) | (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3)});
    moves.add(new long[]{(1L << bit3), (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit1),
            (1L << bit1) | (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3)});
}
```

So I understand that the purpose of left shifting is setting a bit thus a number. So in this case `moves.add{new long[]{(1L << bit1),..` can be converted to

```
BitSet bitset1 = new BitSet(100);
bitset1.set(bit1);
BitSet bitset2 = new BitSet(100);
bitset2.set(//what to set here?);
BitSet bitset3 = new BitSet(100);
bitset3.set(//what to set here?);
moves.add(bitset1, bitset2, bitset3);
```

But I can't figure out what's the purpose of the last two bitwise `or`'s (in both of the `moves.add` lines)

An example - if `createMoves()` gets 1,2,3 as `bit1,bit2.bit3` respectively, it would result in `moves.add(new long[]{1,3,3}` and `moves.add(new long[]{3,3,3}`, because of the bitwise `or` operation on `0001`, `0010` and `0011`

But can't find out what's the meaning of it.

Edit: I think I figured out the meaning and this is my code now:

```
private static void createMoves(int bit1, int bit2, int bit3, ArrayList<BitSet[]> moves) {
    
    BitSet bitset1 = new BitSet(100);
    BitSet bitset2 = new BitSet(100);
    BitSet bitset3 = new BitSet(100);
    
    bitset1.set(bit1);
    
    bitset2.set(bit2);
    bitset2.set(bit3);
    
    bitset3.set(bit1);
    bitset3.set(bit2);
    bitset3.set(bit3);      

    moves.add(bitset2, bitset2, bitset3);
    
    bitset1.set(bit3);
    
    bitset2.set(bit2);
    bitset2.set(bit1);
    
    bitset3.set(bit1);
    bitset3.set(bit2);
    bitset3.set(bit3);   
    
    moves.add(bitset1, bitset2, bitset3);
```

But I'm having problem with the `add()` method because I'm trying to add 3 bitsets to array of bitsets as defined by the `createMoves`. Should I change that to an `ArrayList` inside the `ArrayList`?

Comment: From what I understood, it's not about how many bits you can put, it's about the length of each element in this `long[]` array. In this case each element in the `long[]` represents a move which is in being represented by 3 bits, each bit being a location on the board (in binary), thus if the board is more than 64 cells (bits) you cannot use `long[]` anymore and you have to use something else, `BitSet` in my case. Or I misunderstood it?

Comment: Use `Long.toBinaryString(long)` e.g. `Long.toBinaryString((1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3))`. This will show you the bit positions. Unlike **BitSet**, the ordering starts from right to left -- `1L << 1` == `bitset1.get(1)`.

Comment: But if the board is more than 64 cells? How will I be able to use `Long.toBinaryString`? I need to convert this code to use boards of more than 64 cells

Comment: I expect you to use that method for learning purposes, not really in your code. That **|** is a BITWISE-OR, use it to merge multiple bits e.g. `0001 | 1000` would produce `1001`. Here is an example: `bitset1.set(1), bitset2.set(2,3), bitset3.set(1,2,3)` would give the first `moves.add(bitset1, bitset2, bitset3)` assumes bit1,bit2,bit3 are 1,2,3 respectively. Remember this, the index starts from 0 and not 1 -- BitSet(100) -- [0-99].

Comment: Ok I got confused because the `|` is a bitwise-or and I was trying to use the `or()` method of the `BitSet`, which is logical-or. What confused me is that the result of the bitwise-or is a single number i.e `moves.add(new long[]{(bit, bit, bit)})`, but if I want to convert it to `BitSet` it would result in more than 1 number in each `BitSet` i.e `moves.add(bitset1.set(1), bitset2.set(2,3), bitset3.set(1,2,3))`. I'm still trying to think if the result of the logical-or is equivalent to the bitwise in this case, for example `bitset2.or(bitset3)` as the second parameter in the first `moves.add`

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent. No, this: `bitset2.or(bitset3)` is incorrect. That is equivalent to `((1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3))   |   ((1L << bit1) | (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3))`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's much clearer. I edited my code and you can see the change (at the bottom),  I think I got the logic right, but now I am not sure how to use `moves.add` because I can't just use `moves.add(bitset1, bitset2, bitset3)`, I get error: `The method add(BitSet[], Object[], int) in the type ArrayList<BitSet[]> is not applicable for the arguments (BitSet, BitSet, BitSet)`, and of course, because it's completely different

Comment: `moves.add(new BitSet[] { bitset2, bitset2, bitset3 })`

Comment: Thank you! (*You had a type, first one is `bitset1`). Now I continue and see if I can finish that

Comment: *Also, I had a typo, lol

Comment: @Darkman thank you! It now runs, but I think I have issues again with converting the bitwise logic to BitSet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69698141/converting-code-to-bitset-from-long-it-runs-but-doesnt-solve-properly

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private static BitSet bitset(int... bits) {
    BitSet result = new BitSet();
    for (int i : bits)
        result.set(i);
    return result;
}

private static void createMoves(int bit1, int bit2, int bit3, ArrayList<BitSet[]> moves) {
    moves.add(new BitSet[] {bitset(bit1), bitset(bit2, bit3), bitset(bit1, bit2, bit3)});
    moves.add(new BitSet[] {bitset(bit3), bitset(bit2, bit1), bitset(bit1, bit2, bit3)});
}
```