# Converting code to BitSet from long - it runs but doesn't solve properly

Tags: java

I am trying to convert the following code to use `BitSet` instead of `long` for boards longer than 64 cells:

```
import java.util.*;
 
public class Solver {
 
    // list of seen boards - this is used to prevent rechecking of paths
    private static final HashSet<Long> seenBoards = new HashSet<Long>();
 
    // list of solution boards in ascending order - filled in once the solution is found
    private static final ArrayList<Long> solution = new ArrayList<Long>();
 
    // -------
 
    // goal board (one marble in center)
    private static final long GOAL_BOARD = 16777216L;
 
    // initial board (one marble free in center)
    private static final long INITIAL_BOARD = 124141717933596L;
 
    // board that contains a ball in every available slot, i.e. GOAL_BOARD | INITIAL_BOARD
    private static final long VALID_BOARD_CELLS = 124141734710812L;
 
    // holds all 76 moves that are possible
    // the inner array is structures as following:
    // - first entry holds the peg that is added by the move
    // - second entry holds the two pegs that are removed by the move
    // - third entry holds all three involved pegs
    private static final long[][] moves = new long[76][];
 
    // -------
 
    // print the board
    private static void printBoard(long board) {
        // loop over all cells (the board is 7 x 7)
        for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
            boolean validCell = ((1L << i) & VALID_BOARD_CELLS) != 0L;
            System.out.print(validCell ? (((1L << i) & board) != 0L ? "X " : "O ") : "  ");
            if (i % 7 == 6) System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("-------------");
    }
 
    // create the two possible moves for the three added pegs
    // (this function assumes that the pegs are in one continuous line)
    private static void createMoves(int bit1, int bit2, int bit3, ArrayList<long[]> moves) {
        moves.add(new long[]{(1L << bit1), (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3),
                (1L << bit1) | (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3)});
        moves.add(new long[]{(1L << bit3), (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit1),
                (1L << bit1) | (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3)});
    }
 
    // do the calculation recursively by starting from
    // the "GOAL_BOARD" and doing moves in reverse
    private static boolean search(long board) {
        // for all possible moves
        for (long[] move : moves) {
            // check if the move is valid
            // Note: we place "two ball" check first since it is more
            // likely to fail. This saves about 20% in run time (!)
            if ((move[1] & board) == 0L && (move[0] & board) != 0L) {
                // calculate the board after this move was applied
                long newBoard = board ^ move[2];
                // only continue processing if we have not seen this board before
                if (!seenBoards.contains(newBoard)) {
                    seenBoards.add(newBoard);
                    // check if the initial board is reached
                    if (newBoard == INITIAL_BOARD || search(newBoard)) {
                        solution.add(board);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
 
    // the main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // to measure the overall runtime of the program
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
 
        // add starting board (as this board is not added by the recursive function)
        solution.add(INITIAL_BOARD);
 
        // generate all possible moves
        ArrayList<long[]> moves = new ArrayList<long[]>();
        // holds all starting positions in west-east direction
        int[] startsX = new int[] {2,9,14,15,16,17,18,21,22,23,24,25,28,29,30,31,32,37,44};
        for (int x : startsX) {
            createMoves(x, x + 1, x + 2, moves);
        }
        // holds all starting positions in north-south direction
        int[] startsY = new int[] {2,3,4,9,10,11,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,24,25,30,31,32};
        for (int y : startsY) {
            createMoves(y, y + 7, y + 14, moves);
        }
        // randomize the order of the moves (this highly influences the resulting runtime)
        Collections.shuffle(moves);
        // fill in the global moves variable that is used by the solver
        moves.toArray(Solver.moves);
 
        // start recursively search for the initial board from the goal (reverse direction!)
        search(GOAL_BOARD);
 
        // print required time
        System.out.println("Completed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");
 
        // print the found solution
        for (long step : solution) {
            printBoard(step);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code right now, it runs but not solving:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BitSetEnglishPegSolitaire {
 
    // list of seen boards - this is used to prevent rechecking of paths
    private static final HashSet<BitSet> seenBoards = new HashSet<BitSet>();
 
    // list of solution boards in ascending order - filled in once the solution is found
    private static final ArrayList<BitSet> solution = new ArrayList<BitSet>();
 
    // -------
 
    //private static final long GOAL_BOARD = 16777216L;
    private static String GOAL_BOARD_STRING = "0000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000";
    private static BitSet GOAL_BOARD = bitsetFromString(GOAL_BOARD_STRING);
    
    //private static final long INITIAL_BOARD = 124141717933596L;
    private static String INITIAL_BOARD_STRING = "0011100001110011111111110111111111100111000011100";
    private static BitSet INITIAL_BOARD = bitsetFromString(INITIAL_BOARD_STRING);
    
    //private static final long VALID_BOARD_CELLS = 124141734710812L;
    private static String VALID_BOARD_CELLS_STRING = "0011100001110011111111111111111111100111000011100";
    private static BitSet VALID_BOARD_CELLS = bitsetFromString(VALID_BOARD_CELLS_STRING);
 
    // holds all 76 moves that are possible
    // the inner array is structures as following:
    // - first entry holds the peg that is added by the move
    // - second entry holds the two pegs that are removed by the move
    // - third entry holds all three involved pegs
    private static final BitSet[][] moves = new BitSet[76][];
 
    // -------
 
    // print the board
    private static void printBoard(BitSet board) {
        // loop over all cells (the board is 7 x 7)
        for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
            boolean validCell = VALID_BOARD_CELLS.get(i);
            System.out.print(validCell ? (board.get(i) ? "X " : "O ") : "  ");
            if (i % 7 == 6) System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("-------------");
    }
 
    // create the two possible moves for the three added pegs
    // (this function assumes that the pegs are in one continuous line)
    private static BitSet bitset(int... bits) {
        BitSet result = new BitSet();
        for (int i : bits)
            result.set(i);
        return result;
    }

    private static void createMoves(int bit1, int bit2, int bit3, ArrayList<BitSet[]> moves) {
        moves.add(new BitSet[] {bitset(bit1), bitset(bit2, bit3), bitset(bit1, bit2, bit3)});
        moves.add(new BitSet[] {bitset(bit3), bitset(bit2, bit1), bitset(bit1, bit2, bit3)});
    }
 
    // do the calculation recursively by starting from
    // the "GOAL_BOARD" and doing moves in reverse
    private static boolean search(BitSet board) {
        // for all possible moves
        for (BitSet[] move : moves) {
            
            BitSet move0 = move[0];
            BitSet move1 = move[1];
            BitSet move2 = move[2];
            BitSet newBoard = board;
            
            move0.and(board);
            move1.and(board);               
            
            // check if the move is valid
            // Note: we place "two ball" check first since it is more
            // likely to fail. This saves about 20% in run time (!)                     
            if (move1.isEmpty() && !move0.isEmpty()) {
                // calculate the board after this move was applied
                //BitSet newBoard = board ^ move[2];
                newBoard.xor(move2);
                // only continue processing if we have not seen this board before
                if (!seenBoards.contains(newBoard)) {
                    seenBoards.add(newBoard);
                    // check if the initial board is reached
                    if (newBoard == INITIAL_BOARD || search(newBoard)) {
                        solution.add(board);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    private static BitSet bitsetFromString(String binary) {
        BitSet bitset = new BitSet(binary.length());
        int len = binary.length();
        for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
                bitset.set(len-i-1);
            }
        }
        return bitset;
    }
 
    // the main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // to measure the overall runtime of the program
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
 
        // add starting board (as this board is not added by the recursive function)
        solution.add(INITIAL_BOARD);
 
        // generate all possible moves
        ArrayList<BitSet[]> moves = new ArrayList<BitSet[]>();
        // holds all starting positions in west-east direction
        int[] startsX = new int[] {2,9,14,15,16,17,18,21,22,23,24,25,28,29,30,31,32,37,44};
        for (int x : startsX) {
            createMoves(x, x + 1, x + 2, moves);
        }
        // holds all starting positions in north-south direction
        int[] startsY = new int[] {2,3,4,9,10,11,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,24,25,30,31,32};
        for (int y : startsY) {
            createMoves(y, y + 7, y + 14, moves);
        }
        // randomize the order of the moves (this highly influences the resulting runtime)
        Collections.shuffle(moves);
        // fill in the global moves variable that is used by the solver
        moves.toArray(BitSetEnglishPegSolitaire.moves);
 
        // start recursively search for the initial board from the goal (reverse direction!)
        search(GOAL_BOARD);
 
        // print required time
        System.out.println("Completed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms.");
 
        // print the found solution
        for (BitSet step : solution) {
            printBoard(step);
        }
    }
}
```

I think my problem is in the `search()` method (Converting the bitwise logic to `BitSet`), and also in the way I defined `GOAL_BOARD_STRING` , `INITIAL_BOARD_STRING` , `VALID_BOARD_CELLS_STRING`  and their coressponding BitSetter method `bitsetFromString()`

I can't find out where exactly is the issue.

Comment: Please don't post images of code (or links.  Put the code in the question, properly formatted between three consecutive backticks `\`\`\``  And I would suggest including only a [mre] that demonstrates the specific problem.

Comment: Your `createMoves()` is incorrect. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69698516/17201277) to the previous question.

Comment: WJS, I edited the post. @mokyade thank you. I now edited my code, but the result is the same - the code runs, but it finishes in 1 millisecond without solving. I believe my logic in the `search()` method is also wrong (the way I try to convert the original bitwise operations to `BitSet` code)

Comment: @mokyade, WJS, sorry now I edited

Comment: Can I ask you something -- Why don't you just use existing libraries? I found several when searching for **"java peg solitaire github"**. Some allow you to change the cells too. I've tested the given demo, sometimes it takes a few millis, 1~2 secs or worst 30+ secs. This is a game about choices -- what if there are multiple paths you can take on? What to do? What about dead ends? What to do? Where to begin from? I'd avoid `BitSet` altogether if I were you, using `byte[]` is a lot efficient and cleaner. This way, it is easier to support other boards too or even your own custom boards.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution where you can choose the end board as in this code. I need to be able to edit both start board config and end board config and then get the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying your data.

Lets assume that your code is running the first iteration of `for (BitSet[] move : moves)` so that `BitSet[] move = moves[0];`.

Now when you write

```
        BitSet move0 = move[0];
        move0.and(board);
```

you are actually modifying the `BitSet` at `moves[0][0]` and if during the recursive call to `boolean search(BitSet board)`  you can no longer access the original `moves[0][0]` - but the original `moves[0][0]` is required for the recursion to work.

The workaround for this part is not to use `move0.and(board);` and `move1.and(board);` but to replace the conditions in the following `if` with the non-destructive

```
        if (!move1.intersects(board) && move0.intersects(board)) {
```

---

The second problem is that the line

```
        BitSet newBoard = board;
```

doesn't create a copy of the `board` - it just creates another reference to the BitSet referenced by `board` and therefore the line

```
            newBoard.xor(move2);
```

changes the `BitSet` referenced by `newBoard` which is also the BitSet referenced by `board` which further messes up the data.

Instead of that line you need to create a copy of the `board` by writing

```
        BitSet newBoard = (BitSet) board.clone();
```

---

The third problem is the comparison in the line

```
                if (newBoard == INITIAL_BOARD || search(newBoard)) {
```

`newBoard == INITIAL_BOARD` compares the references to the BitSet's `newBoard` and `INITIAL_BOARD` but because the started as different objects this condition will never be true.

Instead of that you need to write

```
                if (newBoard.equals(INITIAL_BOARD) || search(newBoard)) {
```

Comment: You sir is a genius! Now it's working and I know Java better!